# Skyrim ctd after a short playtime, help!

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, technical-issues

my problem is that my Skyrim crashes after a short playtime each time I play.. There is no specific place, action or thing that causes this (a least as far as I can see). Though sometimes a certain action crashes it each time. An example: Was ctd in arcanaeum each time after reading a few books (got past it by disabling enb). Now I'm in dwemer ruins and one of the I get a ctd when one of the mechanic spiders explodes after I kill it. Note that I can kill all the other spiders up to him without a ctd.
the problem started soon after I bought a new, better laptop and transferred my Skyrim there, copied it instead of reinstalling it. As it was a better laptop I augmented the appearance compared to before. I activated shadows and added enb. Though I ended up deactivating the enb cause it slowed the game too much and made the ctd more often.

Here are infos: 
211 hours in the game (don't know if it's relevant)

Laptop specs: 
Processor Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-7300HQ CPU @ 2.50GHz
Video Card Intel(R) HD Graphics 630
Video Card #2 NVIDIA GeForce GTX 960M
RAM 8.0 GB
Operating System Microsoft Windows 10 (build 15063), 64-bit

Modlist and INIs:
https://modwat.ch/u/peindora/plugins

MemBlocks log:
logging of blocks enabled
logging max values only
Timer disabled
Block1 Block2
512MB 256MB
85 8
85 8

Please help me find the problem and thanks in advance

Comment: got past the spider by reducing the particles from 6000 to 5500. Crashed 3 minutes later when looting a mecha spider.

Comment: Turn off all mods and see if it still crashes.  If not, it's your mods.

Answer (score 1):

You're approaching a limit on mods. The limits on the game for mods is 254, which includes Skyrim.esm and Update.esm, making 256. You're packing in 227 mods to a 32 bit game, which can cause numerous problems.

Your problem appears to be two-fold. You've copied your Skyrim directory instead of reinstalling, and while this seems like an easy way to do it, you've likely encountered more problems than it's worth. It would be best if you did a full reinstall of the game, properly.

Secondly, as Frank mentioned, you'll need to disable all your mods. This is going to be tough, especially considering the size of your mod list, but when this many are involved, it's hard to tell what mods are conflicting or causing issues. The best way to do it is to disable them all, test your game, and begin reactivating in chunks. Again, this will take a while, and it will be a pain in the butt, but the things we do for mods, right?

Comment: I played for 200 hours with the exactly the same modlist. And if i deactivate all my mods I believe that the game won't even load the save because of the missing content. And as it's not related to one specific thing/place/time it would be hard to use this method with new game as well. so they shouldn't be conflicting. I can try to reinstall though.

Comment: Congratulations, and welcome to the world of modding! What works for 200 hours can suddenly stop when a script becomes bloated with overwrites or errors, textures and models and items can become corrupt. Your list is so massive that any of these problems is possible.

Comment: that sucks... I spent a LOT of time making that list... if I remember right there is a way to clean the save. Do you know if it works well and if it's safe? start over my game... I planed to finish the WHOLE game in this save...

Comment: I have no idea, and truthfully, nothing is safe when you're modding. Even one mod could wreak havoc. Just back your saves up if you plan on trying that.

Comment: already backed it all up.

Comment: "reactivating in chunks" - I suggest binary approach. Try one half: good? - proceed to the half of remaining mods. Bad? - divide this half by half and repeat with those halves.